# Same versions of Linux, CC, LD have different link order rules

Tags: c, linux, ld, cc

I have a desktop PC and a laptop PC both running identical Linuxes (Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS) but the desktop has few extra bits and pieces loaded, I would have thought irrelevant, both are running gcc-12 as the "main" one and the same version of "ld" - 2.38.

The contents of /etc/ld-conf.d are the same in each case

Context is I'm working on what is intended to be a C shared library currently with 2 modules "symbols.o" and "stringvec.o". I've stuck a "main" routine on the end of "symbols.c" whilst I debug those modules, so for the purposes of the question I'm asking about a progam.

The makefile has in it:

```
CFLAGS=-g -I incl
LDFLAGS=-lm

all:    symbols

symbols: stringvec.o symbols.o
```

On both machines "make" gives

```
cc -g -I incl   -c -o symbols.o symbols.c
cc -g -I incl   -c -o stringvec.o stringvec.c
cc -lm  symbols.o stringvec.o   -o symbols
```

On the desktop the final step returns to the command prompt with "symbols" built but on the laptop it moans about symbols from "-lm" missing.

```
/usr/bin/ld: symbols.o: in function `getstringvalue':
/home/jmc/src/products/commonlib/symbols.c:176: undefined reference to `nearbyint'
/usr/bin/ld: symbols.o: in function `eval_tree':
/home/jmc/src/products/commonlib/symbols.c:433: undefined reference to `pow'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/jmc/src/products/commonlib/symbols.c:439: undefined reference to `fetestexcept'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/jmc/src/products/commonlib/symbols.c:441: undefined reference to `feclearexcept'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: symbols] Error 1
```

I can get round this easily by putting in the last part of the Makefile

```
$(CC) -o symbols stringvec.o symbols.o $(LDFLAGS)
```

But why the difference? Why is `--as-needed` turned on in one case but not the other? And why is the default make rule "wrong" as it were?

This only came up because I'd worked on it on the Desktop and thought I'd debugged it all and thought I'd just copy it to the laptop in case the urge to further fiddle with it over the next few days whilst I'm away was too strong.

I have tried `-Wl,--as-needed` in `LDFLAGS` but that doesn't seem to help.

I did notice slightly different output with `-t` option to `LD`.

Comment: I don't know off-hand why you observe the difference you do, but I note that the difference would not matter if your makefile were not deficient.  With respect to `make`'s built-in rules, the `LDFLAGS` variable is for linker flags *other than* any specifying objects to include in the link.  If you are prepared to assume GNU `make` then you can use `LDLIBS` or `LOADLIBES` for libraries -- either of these will put the libraries at the end of the link command, where they belong.  If you don't want to assume GNU `make` then you should write an explicit link rule for target `symbols`.

Comment: Side note: I don't think the linker's `--as-needed` flag means what you think it means.

Comment: Wild guess: do you perhaps have a static version of glibc / libc6-dev installed on the desktop (but not on the laptop)?

Comment: The `-lm` should be in `LDLIBS` and not `LDFAKAGS`.  Libraries are files, even when specified with `-lname`.  And libraries should come after object files, in general.  I don't know why the difference, but libraries last is pretty safe.  Sometimes, on some systems, you canlist shared objects early and it works.  Most often, it does not.

Comment: Since you tagged both C and C++ languages, I'm assuming you are mixing them, which is a bad idea.  The C++ language allows for function and operator overloading.  Because of this, the C++ language linker needs to differentiate between them.  The C language doesn't have this feature.  The concept of mixing C++ naming and C language naming is called "name mangling" and may not be consistent across various compilers or linkers.  I recommend choosing one language and adjusting your tags accordingly.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, but are using ".c" files, remember to tell the compiler and linker that you are using the C++ language, regardless of the traditional file extension.  You'll probably want the C++ linking when you mixing C and C++ languages.